# How to set label text to JTextField input

Tags: swing, user-interface, awt, jlabel, cardlayout

I'm trying to get a user to input a name in one panel on CardLayout and for the input to then define a JLabels text in the next panel that it switches to. I used System.out.println(userName); to double check that it was picking up the text and it definitely is but I don't know how to get the 'user' text to be that of the JTextFields input.

Full working code below:

```
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class gameDataPanel {

    private JFrame frame = new JFrame("Game Data Input");
    private JPanel mainPanel, loginPanel, gameDataPanel;
    private JLabel playerName, user;
    private JTextField playerNameInput;
    private JButton submit;
    private CardLayout gameDataLayout = new CardLayout();
    private String userName;

    public gameDataPanel() {

        mainPanel = new JPanel();

        mainPanel.setLayout(gameDataLayout);

        playerName = new JLabel("Enter Player Name: ");
        playerNameInput = new JTextField(30);
        submit = new JButton("Submit");

        loginPanel = new JPanel();
        loginPanel.add(playerName);
        loginPanel.add(playerNameInput);
        loginPanel.add(submit);

        gameDataPanel = new JPanel();
        user = new JLabel();
        user.setText(userName);
        gameDataPanel.add(user);

        mainPanel.add(loginPanel, "1");
        mainPanel.add(gameDataPanel, "2");
        gameDataLayout.show(mainPanel, "1");

        submit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                userName = playerNameInput.getText();
                gameDataLayout.show(mainPanel, "2");
                System.out.println(userName);
            }
        });

        playerNameInput.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

                userName = playerNameInput.getText();
                gameDataLayout.show(mainPanel, "2");
                System.out.println(userName);
            }
        });

        frame.add(mainPanel);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        gameDataPanel gd = new gameDataPanel();
    }

}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not 100% sure, whether i understood you correctly: You want to display the users name, which is entered in "playerNameInput" to be displayed in the JLabel "user" ? In this case, you have to update your JLabel object in your event listener AFTER the user entered something and pressed the push button. Try something like this:

```
playerNameInput.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

        userName = playerNameInput.getText();
        user.setText(userName);
        gameDataLayout.show(mainPanel, "2");
        System.out.println(userName);
    }
});
```

I hope this helps :-)

Comment: This was a straight up fix, thank you very much. Do you mind explaining why it wouldn't work outside the ActionListener? Thanks

Comment: It is a matter of causality: You create an instance of your "gameDataPanel" class, the window shows up, its constructor is executed. Furthermore, your event listeners are registered but not yet executed. The user name field is still empty. The user enters some data, presses the button and now the event listener code is executed and reads the user name from the text field.