# opening a frame by clicking on the button

Tags: java

In my project I am trying to open `LoginFrame` from `WelcomeFrame` by clicking `a button and I want my`WelcomeFrame`to be closed as well.
I have successfully opened the`LoginFrame`by using`setVisible(true)`.
To close the`WelcomeFrame`I have written`frame.SetVisible(false)`where frame is the object of`WelcomeFrame` but this line shows an error: frame cannot be resolved ....

Here's my code.. Please help

```
public class WelcomeFrame extends JFrame{

    private JPanel contentPane;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    WelcomeFrame frame = new WelcomeFrame();   //object of WelcomeFrame
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }



JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Librarian Portal\r\n");
btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
LoginFrame l=new LoginFrame();
l.setVisible(true);
frame.setVisible(false);  //error:frame cannot be resolved
    }
        });
```

Comment: try this.setVisible(false) instead of frame.setVisible(false)

Comment: I have already tried this.setVisible(false) ,but it leads to an error:The method setVisible(boolean) is undefined for the type new actionListener(){}@LasithaYapa

Comment: try WelcomeFrame.this.setVisible();

Answer (score 0):

Because object of WelcomeFrame is not accessible.

You need to create another object before trying to call setVisible method.

```
 WelcomeFrame closing_frame = new WelcomeFrame();
closing_frame.setVisible(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

public class WelcomeFrame extends JFrame{

```
private JPanel contentPane;
private WelcomeFrame frame;
```

after

```
 EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                frame = new WelcomeFrame();
```

I think it'll help you

Comment: thanks for your help...It worked for me  but to implement this i have to make  frame object as static as i have instantiated frame object in main class which is  a static class.But I have no reason to declare it static@Hayk Petrosyan

Comment: if you declare it like static it'll work , so I think it's good reason

Answer (score 0):

a CardLayout is more adapted to your needs; the general idea is to create a jPanel instead of a JFrame, the CardLayout enables you to switch between them by showing only one at a time. if this is what you need [have alook here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38720879/how-to-set-label-text-to-jtextfield-input)